# Enumerate terminal services sessions in Delphi 2007 on Windows 7

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-2007, terminal-services

I'm using QWINSTA.EXE to get the session/user list from a terminal server on our network (my computer is Windows 7 Pro, the TS is Windows Server 2003).  I pipe the output of this function to a text file and then process the text file to get the info I need.  If there is a better way, please forgive and skip my long winded post and point me in the right direction.

My problem is that neither `ShellExecute()` nor `ShellExecuteEx()` allow me to even execute the program without first having elevated privileges.  If you go to a un-elevated command prompt you won't even see the EXE in a directory listing (no hidden attribute, either).  Use a "run as administrator" command prompt and you can see/use it just fine.  You can see it from Windows Explorer in any event.

I poked around a bit and found this gem: [`RunFileAsAdminWait()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717465/delphi-how-to-start-application-with-elevated-status-and-wait-for-it-to-termina) that does not work if I try to call QWINSTA.EXE directly (it fails with the error message: `System Error.  Code: 2.  The system cannot find the file specified.`).  If I wrap everything up into a batch file and use `RunFileAsAdminWait()` on the batch file then it seems to work fine.

I know of, but have not used, [`WTSEnumerateSessions()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383833.aspx).  I have not been able to find much information on it other than the MSDN link I just linked to.  Anyone know of a decent chunk of reference code for using that API from Delphi?  It's not available in the Windows unit of Delphi 2007.

Questions:

1. Is there another/better way to execute an EXE that requires Administrator rights to even access?  Or is that even what is going on here?
2. Is there a better way to get the list of active sessions on a terminal server, especially one that does not require elevated privileges?
3. If I'm stuck using this method, am I doing it "the right way"?

Thank you for any help you can offer!

Comment: Let me see if I have this straight. You want to run an process that requires elevation without provoking a UAC dialog. The only way to do that is to start **your** process elevated so that the processes that it starts inherit that elevated token.

Comment: @David - I probably should have left #1 out of this, but it was the first time I had run into a situation where a file could be seen from explorer but not be found when using ShellExecute() or even viewed from a non-elevated command prompt.  I wasn't sure if I was doing something wrong from the start that was causing the need for UAC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of pipe the result of the `QWINSTA.EXE` you must use the  [`Remote Desktop Services API Functions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a delphi translation of this API check the [`JwsclTerminalServer`](http://jwscldoc.delphi-jedi.net/index.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=JwsclTerminalServer_pas.html) unit which is part of the JEDI Windows Security Code Library (JWSCL). in your case for enumerate the terminal server seesion you can use the [TJwTerminalServer.EnumerateSessions](http://jwscldoc.delphi-jedi.net/index.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=JwsclTerminalServer_pas.html) method.

Comment: Jedi JWSCL has a tonne of cool functionality.   I wouldn't be surprised if WMI offered a way to query Terminal Server Sessions too.

Comment: @WarrenP, the WMI has a full set of classes to access the Terminal services in the `root\CIMV2\TerminalServices` namespace, but unfortunately there is not official documentation about these classes. Because that I just mention the Terminal services API on my answer :)