# DllRegisterServer with elevated rights

Tags: delphi

My program currrent has the line

Status := DllRegisterServer;

which fails on a machine that is WIN7 and the user is not administrator.

Is it possible to programatically call DllRegisterServer with elevated rights?

Or is there some way I can prompt for the elevated rights then use that info to perform the DllRegisterServer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elevation can only be performed at the time of process creation. So you need a new process to execute this code. Your main options:

1. Call ShellExecute passing the verb runas and an exe file. This will elevate the new process.
2. Add the requireAdministrator manifest to an executable and run that.
3. Use an out-of-proc COM server and initiate it elevated.

Of these options, number 1 is likely to be simpler for you. You don't need a separate executable for option 1. You can pass command line arguments that will result in the call to the registration function.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to programatically elevate the rights of a program, only the user are meant to do so. You can instruct the OS your program require elevated rights, for example, by including a manifest

[How to add manifest <requestedPrivileges> info into delphi project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226976/how-to-add-manifest-requestedprivileges-info-into-delphi-project)

You can also decide to allow your program to run without elevated rights (by not including the manifest), but then disable all the actions that require elevated rights or re-launching your program asking for elevated rights when the option is invoked in a non-elevated process (very much like the task manager works with the "show process from all users" button:

[Delphi: How to start application with elevated status and wait for it to terminate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717465/delphi-how-to-start-application-with-elevated-status-and-wait-for-it-to-termina)